# Вызов python скрипта на сервере

Tags: python

Привет.

Мне необходимо обновлять изображение при обращении к нему. Его обновлением занимается python скрипт, но как его вызвать, если запрос идёт по такому адресу (###.com/img/123.jpg) и картинка забирается в подпись на форуме.

Думал сделать редирект с этой страницы к скрипту, а после завершения его работы, обратно, но будет ли такой вариант работать?

Повторюсь, изображение является информером для форума.

Answer (score 1):

может, проще вставить ajax-вызов процедуры обновления? Вы с django работаете?

Comment: Это больше похоже на комментарий, чем на ответ.